# How do I remove multiple selected items from a WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, user-interface

I have a WPF `ListView` with many items in it.  When I select several of them, I want to be able to remove them with a button.  The problem I am having is that I can remove ONE item from the `ListView`, but then when I iterate the second time, I get a:

**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**

Error because of the last removal modifying the `ItemSource` of that `ListView`.  What is the best way to do this?  I tried making a copy of the selected items but I don't know what type to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the collection of selected items in a local variable that won't change, then you can iterate over that without problems.

e.g.

```
var selected = lv.SelectedItems.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
foreach (var item in selected) lv.Items.Remove(item); // or whereever you need to remove them...
```

([`Cast<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406.aspx) and [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) are [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx))

Comment: SelectedItems does not have a toArray() method.  I can't seem to figure out the type to use for the local variable.

Comment: ListView.SelectedItems is a System.Collections.IList and hence has no ToArray method. But you could write: var selected = new ArrayList(listBox.SelectedItems);

Comment: @PetrakovichJ: `ToArray` is a LINQ [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), you need to have a `using` for `System.Linq`.

Comment: Moments like this make me think that C# is a terrible language. Don't get me wrong, I love it, but it can be rather abusive towards me at times.

Answer (score 1):

You could manage a list of indexes to remove and then remove the range.

What is your collection source type bound to your `ListView`?

Comment: It is an ObservableColletion<myClass>.

Comment: This answer is the most correct - you need to manage the Listview via the collection it is bound to. You will get an exception otherwise

Answer (score 1):

my prefered way of doing this is to use a dispatcher:

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
         {
             my_Collection.Remove(item);
         }));
```

Comment: Yes, that will asynchronously remove one item. The question was about how to remove several of them. You won't hopefully do that asynchronously one by one.

Answer (score 0):

If your ListView is bound to a collection of a custom reference type, I think this is the preferred and easiest way

```
YorCustomType[] selected = new YorCustomType[YourListView.SelectedItems.Count];
YourListView.SelectedItems.CopyTo(selected, 0);
foreach (YorCustomType reference in selected)
{
    YourSourceCollections.Remove(reference);
}
```

This doesn't rely on Linq